# MS Access 2007 - How to manage different formatting of controls on subform in continuous form mode?

Tags: formatting, ms-access-2007, subforms

I have an MS Access 2007 subform that is displaying data in continuous form mode. All controls on the subform are bound.

I want to change the colour of a combo box on that subform depending of the state of a checkbox on the same subform. i.e. User checks box - combo goes green. Box is unchecked - combo is orange.

Obviously the checkbox can be in a different state between records on the subform.

However when I change any formatting of the combo box according to one checkbox - the background colour changes for all combo boxes on each of the continuous forms in the subform regardless of the state of 'their' checkboxes! I get the same problem if I set `combo.enabled = false` - all instances of that combo are disabled.

Help! This must be a known issue. Is there a workaround? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional formatting should suit:

[Change the appearance of a control by using conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA010208133.aspx)

[Extending the Functionality of Conditional Formatting in Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139965%28v=office.10%29.aspx)